# RxCrossTable: transformation doesn't work

Tags: r, microsoft-r, revoscaler

I am doing this exercise and I can't find the error.

The data is a subsample of the New York taxi dataset (`mht_lab2.zip` on [Github](https://github.com/MicrosoftLearning/Analyzing-Big-Data-with-Microsoft-R)).

In this current exercise I am supposed to tabulate short and long duration taxi trips against short/long distance taxi trips *without* using `rxDataStep`. Therefore I did this:

```
mht_xdf <- RxXdfData('mht_lab2.xdf') # make sure the xdf-file is in your directory
rxCrossTabs(~dist_rule:dur_rule,mht_xdf,transformFunc = function(datalist){
datalist$dist_rule=as.factor(ifelse(datalist$trip_distance>5,'long','short'),levels=c('short','long'))
datalist$dur_rule=as.factor(ifelse(datalist$trip_duration>10,'long','short'),levels=c('short','long'))
return(datalist)},transformVars = c('trip_distance','trip_duration')
)
```

However it returns me an error:

```
Error in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : 
  ERROR: The sample data set for the analysis has no variables.
```

I tried using the `transformObjects`, the `transforms`-argument and tried using combinations. It consistently returned an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above error message is misleading. The problem is that the as.factor() function does not have a 'levels' argument - you need to use the factor() function.

The following will work:

```
 myTransform <- function(dataList)
 {
    dataList$dist_rule <- factor(ifelse(dataList$trip_distance>5, 'long', 'short'), 
          levels = c('short', 'long')) 
    dataList$dur_rule <- factor(ifelse(dataList$trip_duration>10, 'long', 'short'),
          levels = c('long', 'short')) 
    dataList
 }

 rxCrossTabs(~dist_rule:dur_rule, data = mht_xdf, transformFunc = myTransform, 
        transformVars = c("trip_distance", "trip_duration"))'
```

Comment: oh that is a very silly mistake. Sorry for the angry wording. Thank you :)